# C how to get input correctly

Tags: c, input, scanf, getchar

I'm trying to get a sentence and a letter from the user and for some reason it's not getting the letter
it's not doing the `scanf` the same with `getcahr()`;

```
void main(){

    char str[100];
    char letter;
    printf("Enter a line: \n");
    scanf("%s", str);
    printf("Enter a letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &letter);
    printf("%c", letter);
}
```

tried putting NULL in the letter no difference

Comment: "to get input correctly" --> use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason could be it is taking the new line you get after pressing enter when you get the string.so we need to tell scanf to avoid new line character.try this put a blank space infront of %c this will tell scanf to ignore new line characters.
scanf(" %c",&letter)

Comment: its working but if  i put a string with spaces its not

Comment: So now it is taking the space char . 
try scanf("%s%*c") this will ignore the character right after the string.

Answer (score 0):

//It appears to misbehave depending on the compiler. I was using CLion to run the code below and I add space before the percentage sign in scanf.

// Hope it helps :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char name[100];
    char a;

    printf("enter anything \n");
    scanf(" %s %c", &name,&a);
    printf("%s space   %c",name,a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scanf("%s"` reads a whitespace delimited word, *NOT* a line.  So it skips any initial whitespace on the input, then reads non-whitespace characters up until (and not including) the next whitespace character.  Since a newline is whitespace, it will end this process, but any other space will also end it.

`scanf("%c"` reads a single character *without* skipping any whitespace (same as getchar).  The fact that it does not skip whitespace means that if you use it directly after a `scanf("%s"`, you'll get whatever whitespace character ended the first scanf.

If you want to read a line, use `fgets` or `getline`